# Command line Subversion command for updating files with filter criteria

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to call an **svn update** command with an additional filter criteria ?

### My Requirement is :

At one point, I want to call a batch file which basically should get the latest version 
of all the XML files (*.xml) in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is for DOS shell:

```
for /f %%a IN ('svn %SVN_CREDS% list -R %CM_REPO%/trunk/TargetRootDir 2^>nul ^| FINDSTR xml') do svn %SVN_CREDS% up %CM_REPO%/trunk/TargetRootDir/%%a
```

If you want to export the files, like I need to for a deployment script, you would do something similar:

```
for /f %%a IN ('svn %SVN_CREDS% list -R %CM_REPO%/trunk/PTargetRootDir 2^>nul ^| FINDSTR xml') do svn %SVN_CREDS% export --force %CM_REPO%/trunk/PrTargetRootDir/%%a %STAGING_AREA%\%%~nxa
```

Comment: We use the sliksvn command line tool (http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) from DOS batch files. Those require SVN credentials in an environment variable. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might help you: The following script looks for xml files in the current directory and executes 'svn up' for them.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `find . | grep ".xml$"`; do svn up $i; done
```

Comment: usefull, but it won't checkout the new ones.

Comment: can u pls tell me what kind of script it is?  Though i get the logic but can i perform this on DOS ??

Comment: oups sorry, I was assuming a linux system and did not see the tortoisesvn tag so far. Sorry, I'm a linux guy, that does not have any scripting experiences with DOS/Windows... The script was meant to be executed on linux using a (ba)sh shell.

Comment: This one will work for new files if there's no new directories: for i in \`svn -uv st | grep ".gif" |  grep "\*" | awk '{print $NF}'\`; do svn up $i; done